# Mautic Default timezone is UTC even after changing it to kolkata

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, mautic

Whenever we are accessing mautic reports it is showing time in UTC format in reports.

We have set the timezone to Asia/kolkata in configuration

We have changed timezone on server in php.ini file to Asia/kolkata

Cleared the Mautic Cache

After that restarted the server

It is not changing in the reports

Answer (score 0):

The reports will report in the timezone of the currently logged in user. Additionally the activity tracked on a lead will display in the time adjusted to the relative timezone of the logged-in user.

I would recommend not changing your system time from UTC, and instead changing the appropriate users to their respective Time zones.